# Can't read from linux character device

Tags: c, linux-kernel, device-driver

I am implementing an SPI driver for an accelerometer. The SPI part is done but I can't read values from userspace.

```
static char charDevMessage[CD_BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
...
static ssize_t char_dev_read(struct file *filep, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *position)
{

    int error_count = 0;
    struct xyz_values xyz;
    size_t size_requested;

    xyz = adxl345_get_xyz();
    memset(charDevMessage, 0, CD_BUFFER_SIZE);
    sprintf(charDevMessage, "%d,%d,%d", xyz.x, xyz.y, xyz.z);
    printk(KERN_INFO "MOB: %s, requested size: %d\n", charDevMessage, len);

    if (len >= CD_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        size_requested = CD_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }
    else
    {
        size_requested = len;
    }

    error_count = copy_to_user(buffer, charDevMessage, size_requested);      

    if (error_count == 0)          
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "MOB: Sent %d characters to the user\n", size_requested);
        return (size_requested = 0);      

    }
    else
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "MOB: Failed to send %d characters to the user\n", error_count);
        return -EFAULT;              

    }
}
```

The node has been created when I installed the driver. But when I tried `cat` or tried to read by python it returns an empty string.

`dmesg` says it has been sent to userspace successfully:

> ```
> [ 3094.495972] MOB: SPI Character device has been opened 1 time(s)
> [ 3094.506075] MOB: -349,-512,511 , requested size:49
> [ 3094.514487] MOB: Sent 256 characters to the user
> [ 3094.522646] MOB: Character device successfully closed
> [ 3120.658568] MOB: SPI Character device has been opened 2 time(s)
> [ 3120.668609] MOB: 0,0,0 , requested size:48
> [ 3120.676392] MOB: Sent 256 characters to the user
> [ 3120.684740] MOB: Character device successfully closed
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return (size_requested = 0);` returns 0 and returning 0 means end of file.

Comment: so does it closes the file from kernel side?

Comment: Your first printk has a format error.

Comment: Yes. Doesn't effect the result but fixed. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. When i open the file from c code by using fd = open("/dev/idealSpi", O_RDWR);read(fd, receive, BUFFER_LENGTH); i can read it

Comment: Function `.read` **should return number of bytes** which has been read. In your case it is sufficient to `return size_requested;`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes because i need position=0(not yet but i will) for the next call. Every read call must be a single job. So thats why i return 0. Am i missing something or misunderstood something in the concept?

Comment: Both *immibis* and *Tsyvarev* provided the right answer, but you are still missing the point...

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs yes beacuse i dont understand why i must not return 0 or how does it effects the code? Anyway i ll try it now.

Comment: Because that's why: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html#tag_16_474_04

Comment: @obayhan No, it tells the program that there's nothing to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misaunderstood the concept of the `.read` function:

The reader (user space) sees only *value returned* by the `.read` and interpret it as a **number of bytes which has been read**.

As for *the last parameter* to the `.read` (`position` in your case), its **interpretation is fully up to the driver's author**. Value, pointed by `position`, is initialized to 0 by the kernel core when the file is opened. After that, kernel itself never modifies it.

If you want to always read from the beginning, you may just ignore `position` parameter:

```
return size_requested;
```

Or, semantically better, you may increment value, pointed by the `position`, so it will reflect *total* number of bytes read. But otherwise ignore it:

```
*position += size_requested;
return size_requested;
```

Comment: Oh my mistake. I got your point that you told now. Thanks for your effort (: So then zero means nothing read and negative values means error as usual right?

Comment: No, zero means EOF, which is not the same as *nothing read*. Otherwise yes, on negative return code, userspace will get `-1` from read, and `errno` will be set to that return code, with the difference that it will be positive.